# While working with Unity Loca and Google Sheets using oAuth. Google API keeps revoking Access when used by multiple users

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api

I started recently to work with the Google API to use  google Sheets for our Localization in Unity. It seems to work as needed until i invited more team members to work on and with the sheet. The goal is that a localization team works with the sheet and we pull it every now and then to the unity project.

But the API started to revoke my access to the sheet. Only one team member can work on the sheet right now and all the others geht the "Revoke Token Access" message in Unity. After some research here i found out that the token are only working for some time when the Product is still in the thestphase on the google side, which is the case.

But even when i create a new Token on the google side i still can't pull or push new data to the sheet and get the same error.

I created a new authorization with a fresh token and gave a few members administration rights to avoid this problem. It did not work.

Comment: Can I see the code you are using to Authorize to google sheets?   There are a couple of things that can be the cause of this but i need to see what type of authorization you are using.   Did you create an installed / desktop app.

Comment: we use the google sheets service  in unity while working on it. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/Google-Sheets-Sheets-Service-Provider.html it is connected to Unity Localization. no more code needed. No installed desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Applications in the testing phase, have their refresh tokens expired after seven days.

[image]

What bothers me about what you say is happening is that if someone is using the sheet and someone else tries to at the same the the second person will get that its expired.  Assuming that your over writing the refresh token with the newest one every time this should not happen.   When you request a new access token using a refresh token sometimes the authorization server will return to you a new refresh token.  If it does you need to ensure that you always store the latest refresh token as you can only have 50 outstanding refresh tokens before the older ones start to expire.

I will need to see your code before i can help more.

Comment: The Code that is used it from the unity Google Sheets Loca. You can find it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/Google-Sheets-Sheets-Service-Provider.html  we did not write any specific code in our project to change that.